# Selecting specific elements in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector, 
`myvector <- c("a","b","c","cat","4","dog","cat","f")`. I would like to select out those elements that immediately follow elements containing the string "cat".

I.e., I want `myvector2` containing only "4" and "f". I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: also, it is good practice to avoid using keywords such as "list" as a variable name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myvector <- c("a","b","c","cat","4","dog","cat","f")

where_is_cat <- which(myvector == "cat")
# [1] 4 7

myvector[where_is_cat + 1]
# [1] "4" "f"

myvector2 <- myvector[where_is_cat + 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x[grep('cat',x)+1]
#[1] "4" "f"
```

Comment: The original question does say "elements containing the string 'cat'" - so `grep` may be appropriate when there isn't a total match. If you are not using any actual regex, it might be better to use `grep('cat',x,fixed=TRUE)` though

Answer (score 1):

You can subset list minus its first element (`list[-1]`) by indices where list minus its last element (`list[-length(list)]`) equals "cat"

```
list[-1][list[-length(list)]=="cat"]
# [1] "4" "f"
```

Comment: This may be a good solution, but it really needs some explanation as it leans towards the *obscure side*, especially for someone who is not familiar with R syntax